# How to get the path to the translated node?

Tags: i18n-l10n, path-aliases

I've set up a multilanguage site in Drupal 7. In a template I need to add a link to a specific content node. This node has translations and path aliases like so:

```
node/42 = pathalias_de (german version)
node/43 = pathalias_en (english version)
```

In the template I'd like to call `url()` to get the link to the aliased version of the content node in the current language.

On the german page it should link to `/de/pathalias_de` on the english page to `/en/pathalias_en`

I've tried several variations, like calling the nid, calling the alias, passing the current language object to `url()`.

Is this something `url()` should be able to do or do I need a different function? Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

After looking at the source of the "Content translation" module I've come up with this solution:

```
    global $language;
    $translations = translation_path_get_translations("node/42");
    /*
    Returns the paths of all translations of a node, based on its Drupal path:
    array(2) {
        ["de"]=>string(7) "node/42"
        ["en"]=>string(7) "node/43"
    }
    */
    print l(t('Link Title'), $translations[$language->language]); //l() will return the alias to node/42
```

This will output the link to the correct node alias. Works and isn't overly complicated - still wonder if there's a function that already does this.

Comment: Or use `$translations = translation_path_get_translations(drupal_get_normal_path("pathalias_de","de"));` to search for the alias instead of node id, it's more flexible. You have to pass the correct language though.

Answer (score 5):

```
global $language;

$translation_node = translation_path_get_translations("42");

$nid = $translation_node[$language->language]->nid;

$path = "node/{$nid}";
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential explanations along with your code.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [drupal_get_path_alias fuction](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_get_path_alias/7)

> Given an internal Drupal path, return the alias set by the
>   administrator.
>
> If no path is provided, the function will return the alias of the
>   current page.
>
> Parameters
>
> $path: An internal Drupal path.
>
> $path_language: An optional language code to look up the path in.

As you can make out it takes a path_language parameter. So you could find out the current language and then pass on to this function.

Or simply use [Multilink module](https://drupal.org/project/multilink)

> 1. Designed for multi-language sites. Especially relevant for sites
>      where not all content is available in all languages, or may be made
>      available (translated) at a later time.
> 2. Allows you to easily create in-content links to other nodes, and
>      those links automatically update to point to a suitable translated
>      version of referenced nodes, when available.

Comment: `drupal_get_path_alias()` won't search for translations of a given node, just for aliases already **in** the given language. I found another workaround, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

None of the above answers seem to make correct use of i18n_path. If you want to link to the translated node you should simply enable the i18n_path module and format the path thus,

```
drupal_get_path_alias('node/'.$node->nid, $node->language);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use the [link function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7). It allows you to pass the language as a parameter and it's the appropriate function to create a link with Drupal.

Comment: `l()` uses `url()` internally so it doesn't matter in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Translation Redirect](https://drupal.org/node/1280468) you can link to nodes with language prefix.

This is what it says:

> The Translation redirect module redirects anonymous users (including
>   web crawlers) to the translation of the page in the requested
>   language, if it exists, using a 301 redirect code. For example, if the
>   request is for /de/node/23 and node/23 corresponds to an English page,
>   the user will be redirected to the German translation of the English
>   node if it exists. If the translation does not exist, then the source
>   node content is displayed.

For example if nid 22 is for English version and it has French and German ones then you can simply link to them as fr/node/22 and de/node/22. This 22 can also be any nid of the translated version.

If particular translation is not found for example if you've not added for Japanese, then ja/node/22 will give 404 for Anonymous users.

Answer (score 0):

To get the correct prefix path, I use:

```
$node_url = url(drupal_get_path_alias('node/' . $row->nid));
```

The drupal_get_path_alias() return only the alias, the url() is the one that add the prefix ("en/").

Answer (score 0):

I used the below code snippet to fetch translation node path in a node page without a node load.

```
$current_path = current_path();
$tanslation_path = translation_path_get_translations(drupal_get_normal_path($current_path, '---TRANS LANGUAGE---'));
$node_path = url($tanslation_path['---TRANS LANGUAGE---'], array('language' => (object)array('language' => '---TRANS LANGUAGE---')));
$alias_path = drupal_get_path_alias($node_path);
```

First you have to get the current path and pass this to *translation_path_get_translations()* or as specified above with translation language code. Then get the alias from its system path.

I used this in *hook_preprocess_html()* and works fine for me. Hope this helps.