# How to get translated URL of node with Entity Translation

Tags: 7, path-aliases, i18n-l10n

I've gone this similar question: [How to get the path to the translated node?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/104815/how-to-get-the-path-to-the-translated-node)

But I'm using Entity Translation and it does not work.

I need this to send emails in Localized language in a cron job.$user_language referes to user's preferred language.

So currently I'm using this code:

```
$translated_path = ($user_language->language =='en' ?'' : $user_language->language . "/") .drupal_get_path_alias("node/$nid", $user_language->language);
```

**What could be the right way to get translated URL?**

Comment: What's the contxt? Are you invoking this in a preprocess hook? Where is your `$custom_language` variable declared?  I'd normally use the `$language` global for this, i.e., declare `global $language;` and then use `$language->language` instead of your `$custom_language->language`.

Comment: Sorry .. I've updated it.

Comment: And you're sure that `$user_language` is a stdClass object, rather than, say, an array or a string?  Debug it by doing, say `var_dump($user_language);` and you should see the type and the internal structure.